# Why won't my PHP file connect to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, macos, mysql-error-1045

I'm using OS X El Capitan. Mysql is running and I am able to add tables using the mysql command-line tool. When I try to connect to the database from my PHP file I get a 1045 error. Below is the code:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '*****', 'aliendatabase')
// or die('Error connecting to MySQL server. ');
or die("Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() );

$query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (first_name, last_name, when_it_happened, how_long, " .
"how_many, alien_description, what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email) " .
"VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$when_it_happened', '$how_long', '$how_many', " .
"'$alien_description', '$what_they_did', '$fang_spotted', '$other', '$email')";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
or die('Error querying database.');

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

I have set the grant options as below:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*477A2FE5488EA451D53F4BFE898AA4D4F61B68EF' WITH GRANT OPTION GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

I can't work out why this isn't working and I've tried starting the mysql process with both `mysql.server start` and `mysqld`. Obviously, the asterisks in the connection arguments are representing my password. Does anybody know what I'm missing?

Comment: I should add, I know there are lots of answers to this online, but none of them seem to help in my specific circumstance.

Comment: Have you tried to connect without password ? something like mysql -u root ?

Comment: I can enter the command-line tool by just typing `mysql`. However, if I type `mysql -u root` I get an Access Denied message.

Comment: `root` comes out of the box with privilages on everything, its the SuperUser. You may have done more damage by messing with that GRANT command

Comment: I really think so @RiggsFolly

Comment: Ok, but it wasn't working prior to me changing the GRANT options. That was an attempt to rectify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're granting privileges on `localhost` and then connecting to `127.0.0.1`

Try changing `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` in your connection:

`$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '*****', 'aliendatabase')`

Or at least ensure `root@127.0.0.1` has also been granted appropriate permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did in fact grant the permissions as you said, but when I show grants the 127.0.0.1 has become `localhost`. Furthermore, when I use `localhost` as an argument in the `mysqli_connect()` function, I get a different error because it is not mapping `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. This is a separate problem for me to deal with later.